# moving magento database to separate server

Tags: database, magento, connect

I'm trying to move the database from a magento store to a separate server, but i have problems connection to it. I know I've got to edit the `local.xml` in `/app/etc`, but i am not sure about the syntax.

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
```

Can you give me an example according to the line above?

Answer (score 5):

Domains:

```
<host><![CDATA[mydatabaseserver.com]]></host>
```

IP's

```
<host><![CDATA[192.168.1.1]]></host>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This sounds quite reasonable, this was also my attempt. Surprisingly that doesn't do it. I get following error-report from the store system.

`a:4:{i:0;s:71:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.1.0.9`

Comment: Did you delete everything in `var/cache`? http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/12883/

Comment: Yes, after every change i deleted the whole cache to make that sure.

Comment: You need to make sure your MySQL server also allows connections from remote IPs. Use bind-address = 0.0.0.0 for all addresses in my.cnf or set the specific IP using the same syntax.